# SQL Server 2016 point in time replication tool

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication

I need to run an end of day 'replication tool/application' on a SQL Server 2016 Always-On DB (1 Primary, 2 Sync, 1 Async). The job needs to run at a point in time when the DB is serving limited web traffic but I can't stop the Web/Application layer being up 24/7.

e.g., my requirement is to replicate all data in the DB at 1am.

I was wondering how best to solve this:

1. Create a Backup and Restore of the Async DB and then run the replication tool off this "new DB".
2. Create a DB snapshot of the  Async DB and then run the replication tool of the snapshot
3. Something much easier I'm missing

*Note the tool I'm using proprietary to a product and I can't use any native SQL replication tools.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have an existing nightly backup? Just restore that

Comment: Our backups run after the replication jobs, so they are 24 hours behind per se. We need to replicate and function off the replicated data via the tool